# Laravel - select count from pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 3 tables:

- user
- project_user
- project

My `project_user` is used to track votes.
Users can vote multiple time a single project.

I need to retrieve for each project the number of votes of a specific user.

This is what I tried:

```
$votes = Vote::with(['project'])->where('user_id', $user->id)->groupBy('project_id')->get();
```

This will get the project but I'm not able to get the number of times user vote the project.

How should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and check if it works for your case:

```
$votes = Vote::with(['project'])
             ->where('user_id', $user->id)
             ->select('project_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->groupBy('project_id')
             ->get();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you!